# Namespace variables and loops in jinja

Tags: python, html, templates, jinja2

I am trying to use two namespace variables in jinja. One will decide whether some html will show up and the other variable is used to change the first. However, only my ns.show variable works and I am very confused

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>Release Notes</h2>


{% set ns = namespace(show="true")%}
{% set ns2 = namespace(current="text")%}
{% for item in items %}
<!-- This needs to only show up when scrumName is new -->
<!-- check if the scrum name new. if so use this code -->
    {% set ns = namespace(show="false")%}
    <p> 1 ; current is {{ns2.current}} | scrumName is {{item.scrumName}}</p>
    {% if ns2.current != item.scrumName %}
        {% set ns = namespace(show="true")%}
    {% endif %}

    {% set ns2 = namespace(current = item.scrumName)%}
    <p> 2; current is {{ns2.current}} | scrumName is {{item.scrumName}}</p>
    <p> show is {{ns.show}} 2  </p>
    {% if ns.show == "true" %}
        <h3>{{ item.scrumName }}</h3>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Epic Name</th>
                <th>Story Name</th>
                <th>Release Type</th>
                <th>Release Date</th>
                <th>Epic % Completion</th>
            </tr>
    {% endif %}
<!-- ends here -->
<!-- This show up everytime -->
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.epicName }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.storyName }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.type }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.completion }}</td>
        </tr>
<!-- ends here -->
{% endfor %}

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as for me you should reorganize data in Python code before you send to jinja. And then in jinja you don't need namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You are using namespace incorrectly.

You only need one namespace variable, you can attach multiple properties to that.

```
{% set ns = namespace() %}
{% set ns.show = "true" %}
{% set ns.current = "text" %}
```

Then you never change the assignment to ns, you just update/reference the properties as seen on the two set ns.prop instances.